# cant find my image file [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'F:/cc/train/1(1).png'

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)|

I want to do character identification，I wrote program to randomly generate 26*2（capital and Minuscule）and put it in F：/cc ,and also generate a csv file to store the labels.

I named the images as 1(1),1(2).......1(2038)，all .png files

```
 train_size = 2038
 test_size = 785
 for i in range(train_size):
     buf = 'F:/cc/train/1({}).png'.format(i+1)
     buf1 = 'F:/cc/train_small/1({}).png'.format(i+1)
     image = io.imread(buf)
     image = numpy.invert(image)    
     misc.imsave(buf1, image)

 for i in range(test_size):
     buf = 'F:/cc/test/1({}).png'.format(i+1)
     buf1 = 'F:/cc/test_small/1({}).png'.format(i+1)
     image = io.imread(buf)
     image = numpy.invert(image)
     misc.imsave(buf1, image)
</blink>
```

then have this error:
[[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'F:/cc/train/1(1).png'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9EX1.png)

I'm new to python, thanks for helping

Comment: well, does the file exist?

Comment: yes,I saved images and labels.csv in F:/cc/train and F:cc/test